# Adding a new calculated field in a Query through a VBA fuction

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I’m trying to create a query adding a new calculated field from a VBA function

I’ve an existing table called `QLIK`

To calculate the new field I need two existing fields called `SOCIETA` and `UNBUNDLING` that are included in the table `QLIK`.

The new field it’s called `WBS` and I’m using a `SWITCH Function` (but I guess using some IIF nested would be the same) in a VBA routine because there are too many arguments to create the field with the code buldier directly in the query

Then I call it from an SQL statement like:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB,…, GetWBS() AS WBS_C
FROM QLIK;
```

At the moment I have the following (simplified) code:

```
Public Function GetWBS() As String
Dim WBS As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Dim Q As Recordset
Dim SOCIETA As Field, UNBUNDLING As Field
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set Q = cdb.OpenRecordset("QLIK")
Set SOCIETA = Q.Fields("SOCIETA")
Set UNBUNDLING = Q.Fields("UNBUNDLING")
While Not Q.EOF
GetWBS = Switch( _
[SOCIETA] = "Company 1" And ([UNBUNDLING] = "U1"), WBS = "AAA", _
[SOCIETA] = "Company 1" And ([UNBUNDLING] <> "U1"), WBS = "BBB", _
[SOCIETA] = " Company 2", WBS = "CCC", _
[SOCIETA] = " Company 3", WBS = "DDD")
Q.MoveNext
Wend
Q.Close
End Function
```

But I’m getting the “run time error 94 invalid use of null”. I tried to specify the `GetWBS() Function` and variable `WBS` as Variants but I’m getting only zeros in the new column.

Any ideas of what’s wrong with my code or other ways to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Nz function to handle null values in the fields - this allows you to specify a value that the VBA code can handle when the field value is null. So your code would be something like;

```
Switch((Nz(SOCIETA.Value, "") = "Company 1") And (Nz(UNBUNDLING.Value, "") = "U1") ....
```

This means that when the field value is null the Nz function will return "".